# Does mathematica have support for mixture models?

Tags: distributions, modeling

Does Mathematica have support [mixture models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model)? Similar to the `R` language libraries `mclust` or `mixtools`. The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixtools/vignettes/mixtools.pdf) for `mixtools` is quite good.

The closest support I can find in Mathematica is the `LearnDistribution[]` function as documented [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LearnDistribution.html). I can get a PDF out of this, but I cant figure out how to get parameter estimates out, or to define the number of distributions it should determine, or define any start conditions.

Comment: [`MixtureDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MixtureDistribution.html) + [`FindDistributionParameters`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistributionParameters.html)?

Comment: This is all in the documention. Use `Method->"GaussianMixture"` and the [sub-options here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/method/GaussianMixture.html). For example: `iris = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "FisherIris"}, "Data"][[All, 
   1, {1, 3}]];
ld = LearnDistribution[iris, 
  Method -> {"GaussianMixture", "ComponentsNumber" -> 3}]`. All the information about the parameters is in `ld[[1]]` if you need it - that's poking into the internals of Mathematica so this part is not documented.

Comment: Well, goodness. How embarrassing. Thanks @flinty

Comment: @Q.P. it is a little more complicated than that in fact - I will write up an answer.

Comment: @flinty Yes I can see, I just ran some code. It's also quite different to some of the methods I've seen in the `R` libraries `mclust` and `mixtools`.

Comment: @Q.P. the problem is that the parameters you extract using the stuff in my comment above are nice, but they're for fitting `Standardize[data]` not `data`, because Mathematica always seems to `Standardize` everything before it goes through with the learning. My answer addresses this by trying to un-standardize the extracted means and covariances to fit the original data instead of the standardized data. You can actually see this in `Preprocessor->ToMLDataset,Processor->Standardize` in the `ld[[1]]`. It's a shame I can't find a way to turn off `Standardize` preprocessing in `LearnDistribution`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica often pre-`Standardize`'s data before learning. For example, see my [answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/233599/72682) about learning SVM hyperplanes where I also encountered this problem. Therefore things are a bit more involved than my comment about the documentation if you want to extract the right parameters. I hope you can follow along:

```
(* some sample data, learn a 3 component mixture *) 
iris = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "FisherIris"}, "Data"][[All,1,{1,3}]];
ld = LearnDistribution[iris, 
   Method -> {"GaussianMixture", "ComponentsNumber" -> 3, 
     "CovarianceType" -> "Full"}];

(* extract the parameters from the internals *)
model = ld[[1]]["Model"];
{weights, means, choleskys} = 
  model /@ {"MixingCoefficients", "Means", "CholeskyCovariances"};

(* turn the cholesky covariances into +ve def symm matrices with U.U^T*)
covariances = #.ConjugateTranspose[#] & /@ choleskys;

(* create the mixture *)
distributions = MapThread[MultinormalDistribution, {means, covariances}];
mixture = MixtureDistribution[weights, distributions];

(* we first plot against the standardized points. Mathematica standardizes 
   all data before learning the parameters *) 
pdf = PDF[mixture, {x, y}];
DensityPlot[pdf, {x, -2, 3}, {y, -2, 3}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[Standardize[iris]]}, PlotPoints -> 25]
```

[image: standardized]

In the above, we extracted the weights, means, and cholesky covariances, and we formed the symmetric covariances using $U.U^\top$ on each. Unfortunately these parameters are have been fit to `Standardize[iris]`, not the original points `iris`. Therefore we need to apply the appropriate linear transformations to get parameters that fit the original data.

```
(* we need to unstandardize the parameters *)
sd = DiagonalMatrix@StandardDeviation[iris];
mu = Mean[iris];
finalmeans = (sd.# + mu) & /@ means;
finalcholeskys = (sd.#) & /@ choleskys;
finalcovariances = #.ConjugateTranspose[#] & /@ finalcholeskys;

(* create the un-standardized mixture and finally we can plot against 
  the original points *)
finaldistributions = MapThread[MultinormalDistribution, {finalmeans,finalcovariances}];
finalmixture = MixtureDistribution[weights, finaldistributions];
finalpdf = PDF[finalmixture, {x, y}];

(* Plot it. The ^0.125 is for better scaling and visualization only *)
DensityPlot[finalpdf^0.125, {x, 0, 12}, {y, 0, 12}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[iris]}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: unstandardized]

It looks mostly correct by eye. I'm not sure if my transformations of the Cholesky covariances are correct. Somebody with more stats knowledge might want to verify this is the right way to un-standardize a covariance matrix.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer as it answers the question. But I don't think this is the solution I am looking for, the `R` libraries Implement maximum-likelihood approaches, and I must confess to having no idea how `LearnDistribution` works!

Comment: @Q.P. thanks. Please leave the question up though as this standardization stuff is useful for the community to know. The max likelihood approach is best done in Mathematica with `FindDistributionParameters[..., ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]` (the "MaximumLikelihood" is the default anyway). See my other answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/234210/72682

Comment: @Q.P. by the way, from looking at the ld[[1]] I can see it produces this key: `"LossName" -> "MeanCrossEntropy"`. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-entropy_method) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Cross-entropy_minimization) . Also this appears: `"EMIterations" -> 1` so it's doing expectation maximization.

Comment: That's a very good spot!! Can you see how to get a likelihood number out as a measure of how good the model numbers are?

Comment: It seems GMM in FindClusters failed cluter iris into 3, even by setting `ComponentsNumber`.  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276158/how-can-i-cluster-iris-data-by-gaussianmixture-method-into-three-parts