# How can I cluster Iris data by GaussianMixture method into three parts?

Tags: cluster-analysis

Iris data has three kinds of labels.

```
iris=ExampleData[{"MachineLearning","FisherIris"},"Data"][[All,1,{1,3}]];

c1=FindClusters[iris,3,Method->"KMeans"]

c2=FindClusters[iris,Method->"GaussianMixture"]
```

`Length@c2` gives `2`

I found if I use GaussianMixture method in SKLearn, it returns three clusters.

By default, I think they both use `EuclideanDistance`.

Comment: What are the parameters used in SKLearn? Can you match them to the ones in Mathematica, eg `DistanceFunction` and `CriterionFunction` ?

Comment: @IntroductionToProbability By default, I think they both use `EuclideanDistance`, `CriterionFunction` is useless in one method.